# Using filter to return only specific property of the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have an array object and inside that array object I need to filter and create an array based on `isVerfied` property.

If `isVerfied` property is true,  I just need to push the name property of the object instead of pushing the entire object into an array

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working since it is pushing the entire object.

```js
const users = [
   {
         name: 'Varun', 
         age: '18', 
         isVerfied: 'true'
   }, 
   {
         name: 'Rahul', 
         age: '12', 
   }
]
 
const verfiedUserNameNew = users.filter(user => {
     if (user.isVerfied) return user.name
})

console.log(verfiedUserNameNew)
```

I tried with map as well

```js
const users = [
  {
        name: 'Varun', 
        age: '18', 
        isVerfied: 'true'
  }, 
  {
        name: 'Rahul', 
        age: '12', 
  },
]
         
const verfiedUserNameNew = users.map(user => {
  if (user.isVerfied) return user.name
})

console.log(verfiedUserNameNew)
```

But then it return varun and undefined. i know an alternate solution can be to create an array and run a for.Each loop, put an if condition inside that loop and then push the element into an array

```js
const users = [
  {
        name: 'Varun', 
        age: '18', 
        isVerfied: 'true'
  }, 
  {
        name: 'Rahul', 
        age: '12', 
  },
]
     
const newArray = []
users.forEach(element => {
  if (element.isVerfied) {
        newArray.push(element.name) 
  } 
}) 
     
console.log(newArray)
```

But I was thinking if we could achieve this using filter method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither `filter` nor `map` *on its own* can do this.

You have several options:

1. `filter` and then `map`. This is simple and straightforward and appropriate for arrays up to the hundreds or low thousands of entries (at least), since it makes two passes through the data (well, one pass through all of the data and a second pass through the filtered result). Unless you're dealing with a truly massive array, there shouldn't be any performance issue.
2. Use a simple loop and push to an array you create prior to the loop.
3. Use `reduce`, which people commonly do although it's frankly just additional complication on top of #2.

Here's #1:

```
const verfiedUserNameNew = users
  .filter(user => user.isVerified)
  .map(({name}) => name);
```

Live Copy:

```js
const users = [
  {
   name: 'Varun', 
   age: '18', 
   isVerified: true
  }, 
  {
   name: 'Rahul', 
   age: '12', 
  },
 ];
 
const verfiedUserNameNew = users
  .filter(user => user.isVerified)
  .map(({name}) => name);

console.log(verfiedUserNameNew);
```

I fixed two other thigns in there as well:

1. Fixed the spelling of `isVerified`
2. Used a boolean, not a string, for `isVerified`

Here's #2:

```
const verfiedUserNameNew = [];
for (const {isVerified, name} of users) {
  if (isVerified) {
    verfiedUserNameNew.push(name);
  }
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
const users = [
  {
   name: 'Varun', 
   age: '18', 
   isVerified: true
  }, 
  {
   name: 'Rahul', 
   age: '12', 
  },
 ];
 
const verfiedUserNameNew = [];
for (const {isVerified, name} of users) {
  if (isVerified) {
    verfiedUserNameNew.push(name);
  }
}

console.log(verfiedUserNameNew);
```

Here's #3, but again, this is just a more complicated, harder to read and debug version of #2:

```
const verfiedUserNameNew = users.reduce((verified, {isVerified, name}) => {
  if (isVerified) {
    verified.push(name);
  }
  return verified;
}, []);
```

Live Copy:

```js
const users = [
  {
   name: 'Varun', 
   age: '18', 
   isVerified: true
  }, 
  {
   name: 'Rahul', 
   age: '12', 
  },
 ];
 
const verfiedUserNameNew = users.reduce((verified, {isVerified, name}) => {
  if (isVerified) {
    verified.push(name);
  }
  return verified;
}, []);

console.log(verfiedUserNameNew);
```

You'll see people doing this:

```
const verfiedUserNameNew = users.reduce((v, {isVerified, name}) => ((isVerified ? v.push(name) : undefined), v), []);
```

or similar to make it look like it's simpler than it is, but, well... :-)

Comment: i meant we need to create a temporary variable when we use a simple `for loop` to push values, where as in any of the method `map, filter and reduce` we don't so, so we don't run into a general mistake of naming collision and changing value of that variable somewhere else in code by accident which becomes hard to debug

Comment: @CodeManiac - No name collision concern with modern JavaScript. The `isVerified` and `name` variables in the `for` loop above only exist within the `for` loop, not outside of it. (Granted they shadow any other in-scope `isVerified` or `name` variables, but then, for the duration of that loop, that's what you want.) Extra variables **used** to be a valid issue with using `for` for this pre ES2015, but not since. (In ES5, the solution to that was `forEach`.)

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce`

```js
const users = [{name: 'Varun',age: '18',isVerfied: 'true'},{name: 'Rahul',age: '12',},]

const verfiedUserNameNew = users.reduce((op,{name,isVerfied}) => {
  if (isVerfied) op.push(name)
  return op
}, [])

console.log(verfiedUserNameNew)
```